# How to access to server header via fetch from another domain if cors allowed

Tags: javascript, fetch

How to access to server header via fetch from another domain if cors allowed

example

```
   fetch(item,{method:"GET"}).then((response) => {
                for (let pair of response.headers.entries()) {
                    console.log(pair[0]+ ': '+ pair[1]);
                }
       }
```

I cannot see server header

updated.I see on header response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFkM4.png)

what i see on response fetch method
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgBJw.png)

Comment: Does the server respond with a `server` header in the first place?

Comment: i updated anwser